# Pandas and HDF5

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I have an .hdf5 file that contains multiple datasets (signal,filtered_signal,metadata). Each dataset was created by using a Pandas dataframes.

```
store = pd.HDFStore(event_file_path, mode="w")
store.put("signal", signal_df)
store.put("filtered_signal", filtered_signal_df)
store.put("metadata", pd.DataFrame(event_metadata_df, index=[0]))
store.close()
```

This works perfectly. Now I want to add a column to the 'metadata' dataset.
This is what I was trying:

```
event_metadata_df = pd.read_hdf(event_file_path, key='metadata')
event_metadata_df['prediction'] = [prediction]
store = pd.HDFStore(event_file_path, mode="w")
store.put("metadata", pd.DataFrame(event_metadata_df, index=[0]))
store.close()
```

This does indeed "update" the 'metadata' dataset, however, it drops the other two datasets from the file.

Is there a way to update a single dataset and keep the rest of the file intact?

Answer (score 0):

The second time you open the file you should use append-mode. From [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html#pandas-dataframe-to-hdf): *"an existing file is opened for reading and writing, and if the file does not exist it is created."*

So open it like this the second time:

```
store = pd.HDFStore(event_file_path, mode="a")
```